# String Array showing complete list in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, arrays

I have a GridView of Images, below is the text relating to that image which i have it in a string array. now when i try to print the contents of the array below the image in the gridview, it shows complete list of string of that string array in all the images.
for example 
My String Array is as follows:

```
public static String[] gname = 
{"ImageA", "ImageB","ImageC", "ImageD","ImageE"
    };
```

I get my output below the gridView Image as

```
"ImageA,ImageB,ImageC,ImageD,ImageE"
```

in every image in the grid.

I want ImageA to show under one image and ImageB to show in another. How is it possible. Where am i wrong. please tell me by looking at the code below:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.imageandtext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private GridView gridView;
private GridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, getData());
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
}
public static String[] gname = {
    "ImageA", "ImageB",
    "ImageC", "ImageD",
    "ImageE"

};


private ArrayList getData() {
    final ArrayList imageItems = new ArrayList();
    // retrieve String drawable array
    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));

    // Arrays.toString(gname) is somewhat wrong here.. how to correct it?

        imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, Arrays.toString(gname)));
    }

    return imageItems;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, gname[i]));

Comment: the application stops unexpectedly when i replace the above code.

Comment: I tried to add one more For loop and put the imageItems.add (as suggested by @Deacoy )statement inside it. The String Array gets separeted but the images are repeating five times ( each time for one String in the array). Cant figure it out what's wrong.

Comment: when i put the code `imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, gname[i]));`  it throws an exception at java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.. please help, someone.